# Django: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured

Tags: python, django

I know I am not the first person to ask this question, but I still couldn't find an answer for my situation.

I have a Django environment that works very well, I know I only have one (1) `settings.py` file and I know that my environment accesses it correctly.

I recently added a new endpoint to my project. I defined its URL in `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(PREFIX + r"^v1/alerts/debug$", alerts_views_v1.debug_trigger_alert_notification),
    ...
]
```

It is connected to a method that is in a the file `alerts/views_v1.py` but is not in any particular class:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def debug_trigger_alert_notification(request):
    """
    Trigger an Alert. i.e. Create an Alertnotification.
    This function is meant to be called by the scheduler service.
    """

    workspace_slug = request.data.pop("workspace")
    with in_database(workspace_slug, write=True):
        serializer = AlertNotificationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()

    return Response()
```

When I send a request to this URL, I receive the following 500 error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /v1/alerts/debug
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

In my `settings.py` file, my `DATABASES` variable seems correct (though it is built in a roundabout way):

```
DEFAULT_DATABASES = {
    "default": {  # This DB is supposed to always have the latest version of the schema described by the Django Model
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": os.environ["REFERENCE_DB_NAME"],
        "USER": os.environ["DB_USER"],
        "PASSWORD": os.environ["DB_PASSWORD"],
        "HOST": os.environ["DB_HOST"],
        "PORT": os.environ["DB_PORT"],
    }
}

# Retrieve all existing workspace databases:
try:
    _existing_workspace_database_names = ExistingWorkspace(
        db_user=DEFAULT_DATABASES["default"]["USER"],
        db_host=DEFAULT_DATABASES["default"]["HOST"],
        db_password=DEFAULT_DATABASES["default"]["PASSWORD"],
    ).list_existing_workspaces()
except Exception as e:
    log.critical("settings.py: Error retrieving list of existing databases.")
    raise e
else:
    log.info("settings.py: Successfully retrieved list of existing databases.")

WORKSPACE_DATABASES = {
    db_name_to_slug(existing_workspace_database_name): {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": existing_workspace_database_name,
        "USER": os.environ["DB_USER"],
        "PASSWORD": os.environ["DB_PASSWORD"],
        "HOST": os.environ["DB_HOST"],
        "PORT": os.environ["DB_PORT"],
    }
    for existing_workspace_database_name in _existing_workspace_database_names
}

DATABASES = {**DEFAULT_DATABASES, **WORKSPACE_DATABASES}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ["dynamic_db_router.DynamicDbRouter"]
```

What can I do?

Comment: `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` the engine value for postgresql is that. change it to this one.

Comment: @Exprator that didn't fix it I'm afraid

Comment: `django.db.backends.postgresql`
This should also work, do you have proper psycopgy2 package installed. Try reinstalling. Use virtualenv if you aren't using so.

Comment: @somsgod Currently the project is in a docker container, so I assume that counts as your virtualenv idea? My psycopgy2 package is `psycopg2==2.8.2
psycopg2-binary==2.8.2`

Comment: what is the `workspace` value you are passing ? Can you put a debugger like ipdb or pdb in your with block and check your Database settings there ?

Comment: the workspace value is a name associated with the DB (the DB names are all `worksapce_XXX`) and I have tested the value with a debugger and it is correct. The exact same method contents are used elsewhere in the project and work fine

Comment: Where are you deploying this code? Local or Production and which Os? And you are sure their is no other settings.py file their?

Comment: this is just local but it will eventually be in production, and there is only one settings file